# MsAccess I split a database and now I cannot open it in another computer

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically I am helping my friend with a database that was developed by someone else. The first thing I suggested was to split the database. Once that happened, he sent me the front end, and there is no way I can open it in my computer. It seems it automatically compacts repairs and closes. I never get to see it. I only see the "Access Menu" and recent files list.
I have removed the display form on open, and there doesn't seem to be any autoexec macros.
The first form is a login form that uses a table users. I have converted that table to a local table, but still I have no way to get the FE to open on my machine.

Best regards,

Francisco

Comment: Does it open ok when you launch whilst holding the shift key?

Comment: makes no difference. I have never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Is there an autoexec module? They can be macros or VBA procedures. Are there any timer/open/load/current events on the login form?

Comment: @ChristopherD. - the suggested shift key suppresses all automated code. OP should create a new database and import all objects of FrontEnd. Possibly this file was corrupted during split, transfer, or other.

Comment: How did you split database? Access front/back end or Access with SQL back end? Are both computers on the same network, does it work on your friend's computer and do you have the same access version?

Comment: Same Access version, in fact if I split the original file on my computer, then I can use it, and not him. If I do the split over his computer, he can use it, but I cant if he sends it to me.

Comment: When you split, then the path names to the tables are fixed, and not relative. So you not only require the back end part on your computer, but also have to re-link the tables since the path name to back end tables likely changed. This is why you should be able to hold down shift key and prevent startup code. As noted, if holding down shift key does not prevent startup code then create  new blank database and import everything into that new fresh front end - you can then re-link the table links that also imported during this process to point to your local front end.